# cannot update values of textbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to update values of three textboxes in three different table rows but it is only updating one textbox value in one row. I'm sharing my code please guide me.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
      <input class="ppp" type="text" id="ItemBuyingPrice0" value="10" style="width:55px;" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="Itembpusd0" readonly value="1.22" style="width:50px;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
      <input class="ppp" type="text" id="ItemBuyingPrice1" value="10" style="width:55px;" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="Itembpusd1" readonly value="1.22" style="width:50px;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
      <input class="ppp" type="text" id="ItemBuyingPrice2" value="10" style="width:55px;" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="Itembpusd2" readonly value="1.22" style="width:50px;" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
var BindBPCustom = function (id, BPUSD) {
    var errormsg = "";
    var amount = $(id).val();
    var country21 = $('#CurrencyValue').val();    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: cc,
        data: { amount: amount, country: country21 },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $(BPUSD).val(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {            
        }
    });
}
$(".ppp").on("keydown", function () {
    var cnt = 0;
    var bp = $("#ItemBuyingPrice" + cnt);
    var converted = $("#Itembpusd" + cnt);
    cnt++;
    BindBPCustom(bp, converted);
    alert(cnt);
});
```

I want to change every Itembpusd0,1,2 values on each corresponding text typed in ItemBuyingPrice0,1,2. Currently it is just changing only one textbox value if i type in ItemBuyingPrice0 it is changing Itembpusd0 value but i want this in other textboxes as well. Please guide me

Comment: Why have you got `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` in a GET request?

Comment: @Quentin because i'm getting encoded values from server

Comment: @Quentin is this the problem?

Comment: But that is claiming you are *POST*ing JSON to the server. Which you aren't.

Comment: No, it isn't the problem. It is just nonsense.

Comment: @Usama are you able to get the data from server?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi yes i'm getting data from server

Comment: @Quentin what is the solution for this?

Comment: You are getting the data as object. You need to parse that json inorder to show it on text. Can you show us the data returned from server.

Comment: @Usama — For your nonsense claim that you have a JSON body to your GET request? Just remove the contentType line.

Comment: @Quentin ok let me do it like this

Comment: @AnoopJoshi If you're talking about JSON, then it's the other way around... "You are getting the data as *string*".

Comment: @TJ Sorry i didnt get you. Can you explain?

Comment: @TJ he is setting the datatype as json. So the response will be in json format. Not as plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this` inside an event handler to refer to the element. You can use jquery selectors to access the next textbox as follows:

```
$(".ppp").on("keydown", function () {
  //var bp = $("#ItemBuyingPrice" + cnt); this can be replaced with $(this)
   var converted = $(this).parent().next().find("input");
   BindBPCustom($(this), converted);
   alert(cnt);
});
```

Comment: this work fine, but it is not loading values on keydown for example if i type "1" then it will not write "1" in converted textbox but after "1" if i write "2" then it will write previous "1" in converted textbox, i think there is something wrong with keydown event, can u solve this? please

Comment: i have another three textboxes with class name "sum" can i get the value to each textbox of the row with keydown event?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making things extra complicated.

[Example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/am1npcvn/3/)

```
var BindBPCustom = function (id, BPUSD) {
    var errormsg = "";
    var amount = $(id).val();
    var country21 = $('#CurrencyValue').val();    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: cc,
        data: { amount: amount, country: country21 },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $(BPUSD).val(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {            
        }
    });
}
$(".ppp").on("keydown", function () {

    var bp = $(this);

    var eletoUpdate = bp.parent().siblings('td').find('input:text');

    BindBPCustom(bp, eletoUpdate);

});
```

Comment: your code works but it is changing all textbox values in a row, i want to change just Itembpusd value

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but do you need a for loop?

```
$(".ppp").on("keydown", function () {


    for(var cnt = 0; cnt <2;cnt ++){

        var bp = $("#ItemBuyingPrice" + cnt);
        var converted = $("#Itembpusd" + cnt);
        cnt++;
        BindBPCustom(bp, converted);
        alert(cnt);
   }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.

So here your `data` is an Object and to pass it to `val()` you need to `stringify` it.

```
  $(BPUSD).val(data.stringify());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a loop so it will only ever update #ItemBuyingPrice0.

Put a loop in or use a class selector:

Put the class buyingprice on your inputs you want to update, ie:

```
<input class="buyingprice" type="text" id="Itembpusd0" readonly value="1.22" style="width:50px;" />
```

And then update:

```
$(".ppp").on("keydown", function () {
    $(".buyingprice").each(function(){
        BindBPCustom($(this), converted);
    });
});
```